# Call MediaWiki script from Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki

I created a new MediaWiki project and it's likely I'll need to call some MediaWiki JS scripts from English Wikipedia (I'd prefer to call them instead copy-paste them in `MedaiWiki:Common.js`).

Is it possible to call a MediaWiki JS script from Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible although not necessarily a good practice. You can use [`mw.loader.load`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Core_modules#mw.loader.load) or [`jQuery.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) or any other normal script loading method.